# Duplicate selector when using host-context in angular2

Tags: angular, sass

I'm using a car class for the body element and I want to use it in angular2.

```
<body class="car">
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>
```

I tried:

```
:host-context(.car) h3 {
  background-color: blue
}
```

Converting result:

```
.car[_ngcontent-c42] h3[_ngcontent-c42], 
.car [_ngcontent-c42] h3[_ngcontent-c42]{
  background-color: blue
}
```

I want to remove `.car[_ngcontent-c42] h3[_ngcontent-c42]`.
I only need this class `.car [_ngcontent-c42] h3[_ngcontent-c42]`.

What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set `ViewEncapsulation` as `None`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styles: [`
    .container {
      background: green;
    }
  `],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

You can read more about it [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `::ng-deep` / `/deep/` selector

```
::ng-deep .car h3 {
  background-color: blue
}
```

Comment: can you create a stackblitz or plunker?

Answer (score 0):

To keep component styles encapsulated, try this:

```css
.car :host-context h3 {
  background-color: blue
}
```

So you get only what you need:

```css
.car [_ngcontent-c42] h3[_ngcontent-c42]
```